# Hiding DIV's using multiple dropdowns

Tags: html, jquery

I'm not really sure how to use multiple dropdowns.
I have a web page that lists aircraft in cards; I filter filter those cards by simulator and it works perfectly fine, here is my code.

Each card has a simulatortype associated to it. It can be a combination of any 'xp' 'p3d' 'fsx' -- therefore I use 'like' in my java script to hide cards that don't have some combination.

`<div class="aircraft col-md-6 col-lg-4" data-simulatortype="###">`

Here is my JavaScript that takes the input from the drop down.

```
$( ".simulator-type-select" ).change(function() {
  var selectedSimulatorType = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  var count = $('.aircraft[data-simulatortype*="' + selectedSimulatorType + '"]').length;

    if (selectedSimulatorType == "all") {
        $('.aircraft').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.aircraft-notavailable').addClass('hidden');
    } else if (count == "0") {
        $('.aircraft-notavailable').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.aircraft').addClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('.aircraft-notavailable').addClass('hidden');
        $('.aircraft').addClass('hidden');
        $('.aircraft[data-simulatortype*="' + selectedSimulatorType + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
  } 
});
```

Now I want to add an additional drop down that will have the values: 'cargo' 'scheduled' 'charter'.

I was going to add the following to each div in addition to simulator type.

`<div class="aircraft col-md-6 col-lg-4" data-simulatortype="###" data-flighttype="###">`

I tried this code but I can't get it to take either drop down. My goal is to make either drop down do something; you can choose simulator type then flight type, or vice versus.

```
    var simulator = $('.simulator-type-select');
    var ops = $('.flightops-type-select');
    var count = $('.aircraft[data-simulatortype*="' + simulator.val() + '"]').length;

    if (simulator.prop('value') == "all" || ops.prop('value') == "all" ) {
        $('.aircraft').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.aircraft-notavailable').addClass('hidden');
    }
    if (simulator.prop('selectedIndex') > 0 || ops.prop('selectedIndex') > 0 ) {
        $('.aircraft-notavailable').addClass('hidden');
        $('.aircraft').addClass('hidden');
        $('.aircraft').filter('[data-simulatortype*="' + simulator.val() + '"][data-flightopstype="' + ops.val() + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('.aircraft-notavailable').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

The `.aircraft` is the DIV I grab.

The `.aircraft-notavailable` is the DIV I show if the count = 0; meaning there are no options based on filter request.

Comment: If you came as for as getting it to work perfectly fine at some point, I'm sure you'll be able to debug this yourself. Start by adding the debugger statement as the first statement in your change handler function. Open your Chrome console tab en see what happens. Also in that same console you can enter stuff like`$('.aircraft')` and `$('.aircraft').removeClass('hidden')`. You can fiddle with your selectors much faster that way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after coming cross similar issue.

```
$("select.filter-type-select").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.filter-type-select").toArray(), function(e){
        return $(e).val();
    }).join(".");
    $("div#filter-container").find("div#aircraft").hide();
    $("div#filter-container").find("div." + filters).show();
});
```